# References appearing as a section of Appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am working in the `report` class. I want to have the table of contents to be as below.

```
1 Chapter 1 ............................ 2
Appendices ............................. 3
  Appendix A:  Appendix Chapter 1 ...... 4
Bibliography ........................... 5
```

However, my current code makes it look like this.

```
1 Chapter 1 ................... 2
Appendices .................... 3
  A  Appendix Chapter 1 ....... 4
  2  Bibliography ............. 5
```

The code is below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} 

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    Lorem ipsum.... \cite{Hello}
    
    \begin{appendices}
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
        \makeatletter
        \addtocontents{toc}{%
            \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
            \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
            \let\protect\l@subsection\protect\l@subsubsection
        }
        \makeatother
        
        \chapter{Appendix Chapter 1}
        Appendix here.
        
    \end{appendices}
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{refs} 
\end{document}
```

If I add the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` before the bibliography to reset the tocdepth, the Bibiliography entry disappears from the table of contents.

So two questions:

1. How to get the bibliography listed at the same level as chapters?
2. How to list the appendix chapters in the form of "Appendix A:", "Appendix B:" so on in the table of contents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You ask two questions whereas we prefer single questions.

This is an answer to your problem of getting the bibliography listed like a chapter.

```
% apptocprob.tex  SE 625775

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc
        %,numbib % do not number the bibliography
       ]{tocbibind} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
Lorem ipsum.... \cite{Hello}

\begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \let\protect\savel@chapter\protect\l@chapter
        \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
        \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
        \let\protect\l@subsection\protect\l@subsubsection
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \chapter{Appendix Chapter 1}
    Appendix here.

    % make chapters look like chapters, not sections
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\savel@chapter
    }
    \makeatother
    
\end{appendices}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
 % \bibliography{refs}    % you have not provided this
 \bibliography{jobname}  % I have not provided it, but for me it         does result in a bibliography
\end{document}
```

When you start the appendices in the ToC you make chapters appear as sections but as you want the bibliography (equivalent to a chapter) to be set as a chapter you have to reverse the chapter-to-section specification.

Regarding your other question please read the `tocloft` package manual.